# Mule Session vars null in poll

Tags: mule

I am setting a session var to true in a flow A. I have a poll in another flow B that checks periodically if the session var is true but i am always getting null. Why is the session var value null in poll in flow B?

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="poll-session-varFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/sessionvar" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="In flow A..." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="sVar" value="#[true]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
</flow>
<flow name="poll-session-varFlow1">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <logger message="Polling..." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </poll>
    <logger message="value of sVar : #[sessionVars.sVar]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Mule [Variable Scope](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/variable-transformer-reference#flow-scope-versus-session-scope) doc:

> Session variables set with a session variable transformer persist for the entire message lifecycle, regardless of transport barriers.

Unless you are somehow polling Messages generated from Flow A in Flow B, you cannot access Session Variables from Flow A. Your Session Var is probably null because the Flow B Poll generated a new Message with its own set of Session Vars.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to share how you are setting your variable?
This is how I am using a variable and then referencing a flow that uses it.

```
<set-variable variableName="ImportMonth" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Month"/>
<flow-ref name="another-flow" doc:name="another-flow"/>
```

This is how I am validating that there is something in that variable in "another-flow"

```
<logger message="#[flowVars['ImportMonth']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

I hope this helps.